# floating commas, decimal point are too high

Tags: punctuation

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{Results}
\label{sec:res}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{hello2 testing}
\label{1234}

\begin{tabular}{l d{5} d{4}}

          & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Z-t-tilde-bar} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{p-value} \\
NPLr      & -10.8886      & 0.0000  \\
UNEMP     & -3.8959       & 0.0000  \\
LTINT     & -2.8569       & 0.0021  \\

\end{tabular}

\end{table}

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to put this table into one column of my two column document, work, but the comma is too high. Don't know if you can see this from the code, nevertheless any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `.` instead of `\cdot`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `D{.}{\cdot}{4}` (or whatever digit you specify) means that `.` is taken as the input decimal separator and `\cdot` as the output separator.

If you replace `\cdot` by `.` you get the normal period.

However, I recommend using `siunitx`, which allows many more customizations.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Results}
\label{sec:res}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{hello2 testing}
\label{1234}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=-2.4]
 S[table-format=1.4]
}
\toprule
          & {Z-t-tilde-bar} & {p-value} \\
\midrule
NPLr      & -10.8886        & 0.0000  \\
UNEMP     & -3.8959         & 0.0000  \\
LTINT     & -2.8569         & 0.0021  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

\end{document}
```

You need no `\multicolumn`: braced entries in `S` columns are automatically centered.

[image]